# Understanding the specifics of the jquery text() with HTML Entities

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-entities

I have trouble understanding the specific of the jquery `text()` function in combination with HTML Entities. It seems to be that the `text()` function converts special HTML Entities back to normal characters. In particular, I am unsure how this code snippet behaves:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var value = $("#test").text();
  console.log(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
  &lt;h1&gt; test &lt;/h1&gt;
</div>
```

since the output seems to be a string where HTML Entities are unescaped. Does this mean that the `text()` function unescapes HTML Entites?

EDIT/FOLLOW UP:
Since `text()` seems to only return the real text content, I have trouble understanding this code snippet, which returns an unescaped . If `text()` returns the escaped string, why does the `html` function return a formatted one?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var value = $("#test").text();
  console.log(value);
  $("#test").html(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
  &lt;h1&gt; test &lt;/h1&gt;
</div>
```

Comment: Yes! This will give `&amp;lt;h1&amp;gt; test &amp;lt;/h1&amp;gt;`

Comment: Thanks! I edited the questions and added a follow up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`text()` isn't doing anything special. The browser itself translates entities into their rendered characters when it parses the original HTML. So when you write `&lt;h1&gt;` in the HTML, the browser converts this to the literal string `<h1>`. `.text()` simply returns this text.

When you then use `.html()`, this causes the string to be parsed as HTML, so `<h1>` is rendered as an HTML tag, and you get the formatted result.

Answer (score -1):

If you look at the source you'll see that it is pulling out the textContent from elements.
https://j11y.io/jquery/#v=git&fn=jQuery.fn.text

Some documentation of what textContent is:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var value = $("#test").text();
  console.log(value);
  //https://j11y.io/jquery/#v=git&fn=jQuery.fn.text
  console.log($("#test").get(0).textContent);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
  &lt;h1&gt; test &lt;/h1&gt;
</div>
```